# Action bar Icon isnt working in API 21

Tags: android

i used to use the action bar icon but when i do someting on it on API 21 nothing is display no icons i mean only the 3 dot not the icon i want whereas i the api 14 it's working :

menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.gweltaz.idee.Historique">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/sup"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_historique, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM story2");


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: What theme and activity class are you using?

Comment: Do you try my solution? If it was helpful for you please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

to

```
app:showAsAction="always"/>
```